# How can I speed up my system?

Tags: unity, system

I want to speed up my system. How can i use crontab to automate the deletion of unnecessary files and cache ? In what other ways can i speed up my system ?
I have disabled most of the startup applications to boot my system faster.

Comment: Excess files don't cause a system to boot slower. My windows 10 install boots just as fast now as it did 3tb ago.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider making hardware improvements, SSDs are a good option.

Comment: Adding more RAM also improves the general system speed when a couple of programs are loaded.

Comment: @adampski Apart from making hardware improvements. What else can i do to improve the speed of my processes ?

Comment: @Kevlnski Which is a better option to consider ? Upgrading RAM or processor ?

Comment: @KevInski except increasing ram doesn't increase speed unless you're already using all of your ram.

Answer (score 0):

1.increase the  RAM 
2.uninstall flash 
3.increase swap size while installing os for dual boot
4.keep always updated  s/w's  and os 
5.reduce the display resolution ( it may works some time )
6.keep less  contents in internal HDD 
7.put only one os in machine 
8.only enter trusted websites (less virus)
9.put high RPM and  buffer sized HDD (Spindle speed ex 7200 rpm)

Answer (score 0):

Mount root file system with **noatime** parameter. It will not update atime stamps when reads files from the file system.

You can add that in /etc/fstab file.